# ` operator in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

What does the ` operator do in OCaml?

```
let int_of_meth = function
  | `GET     -> 0
  | `POST    -> 1
  | `PUT     -> 2
  | `DELETE  -> 3
  | `HEAD    -> 4
  | `PATCH   -> 5
  | `OPTIONS -> 6
  | _        -> failwith "non standard http verbs not supported"
```

I can't find it in the OCaml manual.

Comment: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual006.html#toc36

Answer (score 7):

This `` ` `` is not really an operator. It works at the lexical level (like quotes for strings) and makes the following symbol into a "polymorphic variant". See the link given by @Edgar Aroutiounian:

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual006.html#toc36

**Update**

Actually, `` ` `` is scanned as a separate symbol as noted by @gsg. So a polymorphic variant like `` ` Abc `` is a syntactic construct. I would still claim it's not an operator in the usual sense.

(Edit: changed to Abc. I never knew they were supposed to be capitalized. For example, the lablgl interface seems to use lower case consistently.)

Comment: It's not really like string quotes: the ` and the symbol are separate tokens and there can be whitespace between them.

Comment: I did not know you could include whitespace! Such a trivial fact but it tremendously changes the way I think about polymorphic variants.

Comment: You are right, I just checked lexer.mll. I will update my answer.

Comment: I noticed that fact: that's the reason why you cannot use ocaml keywords for polymorphic variants (which is annoying for words like "or", "and" — if you look at the lablgl library for instance, certain variants have an underscore appended for this very reason).

Comment: well, according to the manual, polymorphic variants should start from the upper letter, so there is no clash with keywords. But many people (including myself) do not obey to this requirement.

Comment: @ivg indeed! I would have preferred to have pv tags be lexed as one token, though, I suppose there's a good reason for that not being the case.

Comment: I didn't even know you could have non-capitalized pvs!